# Modificar Reporte RDLC en C# Escritorio Windows Form

Tags: c#, windows-forms, rdlc

Tengo Una aplicación de escritorio que hace bastante tiempo no se modifica necesito arreglar unos informes pero al Modificar el .rdlc No Aparece el cambio no se si debe hacer algo mas o usar algun software.

Este el código donde llama el reporte

```
localReport = reportViewer2.LocalReport;
localReport.ReportPath = "Vista/Cartera/Reporte_Seguro.rdlc";
reportViewer2.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
Identificador = "SI";

if (Seleccion == "-1")
{                                        
    tabla1.Cartera_Total_Seguro(Data_Cartera.DataTable1, FEC_COR,FEC_INI, Identificador);
    this.reportViewer2.RefreshReport();
}
```

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Como modificas el informe, con VS2010??

Comment: Hola, podrias decir si la respuesta dada te fue util, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto quizá te sirva:

Cuando uno modifica el diseño de su reporte(**fichero rdlc**) para que se refleje el cambio hecho debe volver a enlazar el reporte al **control reportviewer** del formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se da clic sobre el **control reportviewer** y  en la esquina superior derecha, saldrá una flechita, al dar clic sobre esta flechita se desplegara un menú, en este menú dar clic en la opción **"Rebind Data Sources"**(en la versión de ingles de Visual Studio), y al dar clic sobre esta opción ya se reflejaran los cambios hechos en la vista.